# How to bundle each node_module as separate bundle in webpack?

Tags: webpack

I have a React project where we are using many dependencies. I was following [this hackernoon post](https://hackernoon.com/the-100-correct-way-to-split-your-chunks-with-webpack-f8a9df5b7758) in which the author mentions how to split each `node_module` as a separate file as `npm-package1.js`,  `...2.js`, etc.

How do I achieve it in my webpack configuration? My current webpack config which I have been trying to tinker with:

```
const prodWebpackConfig = {
  entry: {  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'initial'
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I am running this file which always generates app, runtime, styles and vendor.js in my dist. I am not able to see all the NPM packages as bundles. How do I achieve this configuration?

Comment: Check this webpack configuration example: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksname

Comment: Check the name function and also don't forget to override `splitChunk.minSize`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the intended links to the author's Gists aren't working correctly, but you can still see them on GitHub. The `webpack.config.js` for those examples looks like:

> ```js
> module.exports = {   entry: {
>     main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
>     ProductList: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/ProductList/ProductList.js'),
>     ProductPage: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/ProductPage/ProductPage.js'),
>     Icon: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Icon/Icon.js'),   },   output: {
>     path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
>     filename: '[name].[contenthash:8].js',   },   plugins: [
>     new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(), // so that file hashes don't change unexpectedly   ],   optimization: {
>     runtimeChunk: 'single',
>     splitChunks: {
>       chunks: 'all',
>       maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
>       minSize: 0,
>       cacheGroups: {
>         vendor: {
>           test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
>           name(module) {
>             // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
>             // or node_modules/packageName
>             const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
>
>             // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
>             return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
>           },
>         },
>       },
>     },   
>   }, 
> };
> ```

Source: https://gist.github.com/davidgilbertson/c9af3e583f95de03439adced007b47f1

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe for the gist and also the edit it works , i feel the post highlights a lot of best practises for bundling a application for a end user , Just want to have you opinion the same , this leaves me with one less thing to worry abt